# how to make text input NOT left align when onblur

Tags: javascript, html, textinput, onblur

When the width of contents in the text input is larger than the width of the text input,
the contents will align left when the user fires the onblur event.

I'm looking for a method **NOT** to left align the contents when the user fires the onblur event.

I tried:

```
    inputText.onblur = function() {
        inputText.scrollLeft = inputText.scrollWidth - inputText.clientWidth;
        alert("onblur");
    }
```

This method doesn't work. Because it seems like the contents align left after the onblur event ends.

Also I think there is no other events is fired except onblur, I'm not sure. If it's true, it really confuses me and I wonder what makes it align left.

Welcome to any helpful replies!
Hope the solution could be in **javascript** and it worked in **Chrome**.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try delaying execution by a fraction of a second:

```
inputText.onblur = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        inputText.scrollLeft = inputText.scrollWidth;
    },1);
};
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, and I found another way that catch another event which is just happened after onblur event.